# Task Pane Addin for outlook Web app

Tags: javascript, office365, office-addins, outlook-web-app, outlook-web-addins

By command Add-in, task pane is going to appear to the right side of outlook desktop app. Similarly, is it possible to have task pane to appear to the right side in the Outlook Web app?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Following up with this. [Addin Commands](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/exchangedev/2017/01/20/add-in-commands-in-owa-and-outlook-on-the-mac/) are now available on Outlook on the Web (OWA) and Outlook for Mac. If you have implemented an Addin Command for Outlook, it should work without modification for the newly implemented platforms.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, at the time of the writing it is not supported yet. Task pane in outlook web add-ins is only available in Outlook desktop 2016.

**EDITED**

See [this link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/mt267547.aspx#sectionSection1) from MSDN. It reads

> Currently, it can only specify the desktop (DesktopFormFactor).

It makes me think that Microsoft plans to support this for other client as well.
There is also a UserVoice site [here](http://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-general/category/131778-outlook-add-ins) to ask for requests on Office web addins.

Comment: Thanks for response. But also i have seen task pane appearance in right side when in composing an email(Outlook Web App). Is it default thing provided by microsoft?

Comment: Can you show (with a screenshot) which task pane are you referring to?

Comment: He probably means the Find Time and My Templates add-ins from Microsoft.  AFAIK this hasn't been exposed to us measly non-MS developers yet!

Comment: That is the Compose add-in shape. So not the same thing as the Task pane shape.

Answer (score 1):

Good news :), Add-in commands will be rolling out soon to all users and all add-ins for Outlook Web and we expect it to be at a 100% in the month of Dec. Once its rolled out you'll be able to have buttons in OWA that launch task pane to the right as requested, similar to how it is in desktop outlook.