# Outlook 365 vertical task pane in read mode?

Tags: javascript, xml, outlook, office365

I'm creating an add-in for Office 365, and my question is for Outlook 365.

When reading your mail, you can make an add-in show a horizontal pane above each email. However, I'm wondering if it would be possible to also show a vertical taskpane on the side in read mode (like the taskpane in edit mode), or if it is possible to add a button the navigation bar near the top:

[image]

(I don't have enough rep to add office-365 as a tag)

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35745672/office-365-outlook-add-in-can-i-show-task-pane-in-mail-view-mode) topic also addresses a similar issue.
[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35356124/task-pane-addin-for-outlook-web-app) topic may also pose the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. At present, the Office add-in doesn't support the vertical task pane for the Outlook online.

You may leave the feedback from [here](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/) if you require this feature.

Answer (score 0):

While Outlook add-ins don't currently support the vertical task pane in read mode for Outlook on the web, it is available in Desktop Outlook if you use add-in commands and add support for version overrides 1.0 to your manifest.

More information on add-in commands can be found here: https://dev.office.com/docs/add-ins/outlook/add-in-commands-for-outlook